Is it possible to peek into a mutable reference of an iterator?
I have a function that takes a mutable reference to an iterator.
Within that function I want to peek the iterator to check if there are remaining items in it. If this is the case, I want to return an error and the iterator shall not be advanced.
MRE:
fn process<I>(iter: &mut I) -> bool
where
    I: Iterator<Item = char>,
{
    iter.peekable().peek().is_some()
}

fn main() {
    let mut iter = "Hello, world!".chars().into_iter();
    process(&mut iter);
    assert_eq!(iter.next(), Some('H'));
}

This, however, does not work, as I naively expected. Link
Is it possible to peek into an iterator, if all I have is just a mutable reference to it?
Since I do not want to change the function's signature due to compatibility reasons, I currently work around this issue, by returning the value of iter.next() if it is Some() in an error enum variant within the function's Result, so that it does not get lost.

Original use case
Test case


This is not possible, since the Iterator trait does not provide a way to do that. It only provides a next() method, and that method advances the iterator.
You can improve on your current solution by not returning a custom enum, but rather returning the Peekable directly, so you can use it an iterator.

peek() does actually advance the iterator. Peekable works by stashing the value returned by next() in a field on the peekable struct. So the first time you call peek() you will advance the iterator. Since you're not returning the Peekable value, the stashed value is lost and the iterator has advanced one step.
